# Reference table to same table in another database

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I'm currently working on a bigger project with a few friends of mine. However, at the moment, we have a ... pretty bad development setup. Here an - extremely simplified - database:

```
--------------
| characters |
--------------
|   items    |
--------------
|   config   |
--------------
```

Characters and items store some data that is not too important - if something is missing or too much information is in the table, nothing really happens. However, the config database stores some important data, for example active modules. Now, when I work on something and I create a new module required for the main page, for example, everyone else has to pull my branch in git and activate the module, otherwise he can't work.

Our "solution" was that everyone gets his own database. This leads to another problem: When we need an up-to-date database, we have to export our config, delete our database, copy the new database, truncate the config and import our config. That's ... not really professional and annoying to do.

Now, my "idea" was something like this:

```
database user1_project        database main_project
--------------                --------------
| characters | --------|--->  | characters |
--------------         |       --------------
|   items    | --------|--->  |   items    |
--------------         | |    --------------
|   config   |         | |
--------------         | |
                       | |
database user2_project | |
--------------         | |
| characters |  ------>| |
--------------           |
|   items    |  -------->|
--------------
|   config   |
--------------
```

So, what I'd like is one main database that stores the tables `characters` and `items`. And then I'd like two (or any number really) databases that store the config tables. Also, these databases "reference" to their equivalent in the database `main_project`. So, the queries `SELECT * FROM user1_project.characters` and `SELECT * FROM user2_project.characters` pull their information out of the database `main_project`, but the queries `SELECT * FROM user1_project.config` and `SELECT * FROM user2_project.config` return whatever is stored in their own tables without any reference to the `main_project` table.

We're using MySQL 5.5.60-0+deb7u1. We'd prefer a solution for this specific version, if that's not possible, we're not hesitant to upgrade.

Comment: Would you consider switching to MariaDB?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Since MySQL is very similar to MariaDB, yes, switching should not be a problem.

Comment: In that case, I think you'll find the "connect" engine quite interesting.

Comment: By "another database" do you mean in the same instance of MySQL?  Or in another server?

Comment: @RickJames I mean the same mysql instance, just another database.

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve the goal *as stated*.  This is because `user1_project.characters` will only talk to the table already named `user1_project.characters`.

You *could* change that to `user1_project.local_characters`, then have a `VIEW` called `user1_project.characters` that simply reaches into `main_project.characters` (which is still a real table).

Meanwhile `user1_project.config` can be another `VIEW` that reaches for whatever combination of tables from databases.